# How to fix expression injection in app written in grails 2.3.8?

Tags: java, spring, grails

I have an app that is written in 2.3.8. We ran a series of tests on it and found out that it suffers from expression injection issue. This issue seems to be from spring version <3. I am looking for the solution to mitigate the issue. Looks like the spring version that needs to be changed to higher to fix it but since grails is tightly coupled with spring it would not be possible. Is there any other way to check for the incoming parameters maybe at filter level and block all the parameters with issues?

Answer (score 1):

Grails 2.4 comes with Spring 4.0.4.

Upgrading from 2.3.8 to 2.4 should not be too much of a headache.